# Prove that Multiset and relation $\preccurlyeq$ is a lattice ($\preccurlyeq$ is defined like $\leq$)

Tags: relations, order-theory, lattice-orders, multisets

Multiset is a set that can have more than one of each member for example $\{1,3,3,9\}$ is a Multiset. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the set of all multisets that has exactly $k$ members. ($k$ is a fixed constant) (The multisets in this question only include numbers). We define relation $\preccurlyeq$ between two multisets $A,B$ as $A\preccurlyeq b$ if and only if **there exists an order of elements** of A and B like $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_k)$ , $(b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n)$ such that $\forall i\leq k ; a_i\leq b_i$ for example $\{1,3,3,9\} \preccurlyeq \{1,3,4,9\} $. Prove that $(\mathbb{K},\preccurlyeq)$ is a lattice.

My approach for this question: For every two multisets, we must introduce a glb and lub. At first, For every two multisets in $K$, I sort the members Decreasingly. then the GLB is the multiset that has $(min(a_1,b_1) , ... , min(a_k,b_k))$ and then for LUB I sort the members increasingly and he LUB is $(max(a'_1,b'_1),...max(a_k,b_k))$. I think my answer makes sense but I can't prove this formally.

Comment: Is there any advantage in changing the order? It seems to me that you can define glb and lub either with the elements in increasing or decreasing order using min and max...

Comment: Yes, N$^k$ with the product order  is a lattice.